# Is it possible (and how) to remove unutilized widgets from Ext JS library?

Tags: javascript, extjs, size

Ext JS base and widgets together offer me the solution I've been looking for. The Ext JS library is somewhat heavy w.r.t. conventional standards.

There are several widgets in the library that I am not using. So I want to know if it is possible to remove the corresponding code (of widgets not being used) from the ext-all.js ?

To put it in other words, is it possible to compose a master Java Script of Ext JS that comprises of only the widgets of my interest? If there is a way I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, though some of the components are easier to remove than others, as there are dependencies.

Use JSBuilder. http://www.extjs.com/products/jsbuilder/
You need Java to run it.

Then, in the extjs distribution there is a file in each branch named "ext.jsb2", which is the JSBuilder project file.

Copy that file to something like "ext-custom.jsb2", then carefully remove components you don't need, then run a command like this:

> java -jar JSBuilder2.jar --projectFile C:\extjs\branches\ext-3.1.x\ext-custom.jsb2 --homeDir C:\ext-custom

The output will be in the custom directory, and you'll have ext-all.js, etc. with just your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. That tool is available on their site.
[JSBuild2](http://extjs.com/products/jsbuilder/) is created by ExtJS team for that purpose. You just edit [ext.jsb2](http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?p=354473) file appropriately.

There is an old [page](http://www.extjs.com/products/extjs/build/) and a forum [thread](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=21207&page=14).