# Split ExtJS for incremental (on demand) download

Tags: extjs, split, ondemand, coolite

I had [earlier asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456266/is-it-possible-and-how-to-remove-unutilized-widgets-from-ext-js-library) whether I can remove un-utilized JavaScript code from ExtJS library. [JSBuilder](http://www.extjs.com/products/js/build/) was the answer.

What about being able to download widgets on-demand? I ask this because I have discovered this from the of markup generated by [Coolite](http://www.coolite.com/) (ASP.Net framework that wraps ExtJS). So do I have to go through a meticulous process of splitting the library myself or is there a better way? BTW I'd like to avoid using Coolite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?p=225658#post225658